# Find type class instance for Shapeless HList in Scalaz state monad

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz, shapeless

Say that I have a state monad with the state is an `HList` and I define a combinator that takes the first `n` elements of this `HList`:

```scala
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import shapeless._,  ops.hlist._, Nat._

def take[S <: HList](n: Nat)(implicit tk: Take[S, n.N]):
    IndexedState[S, tk.Out, Unit] = ???

for {
  _ <- init[Int :: String :: HNil]
  _ <- take(_1)
  x <- state("abc")
} yield x
```

The scala compiler gets stuck during type inference. It doesn't infer that the `S` type parameter of `take` is an `Int :: String :: HNil`. Thus, the compiler cannot find implicit value for parameter `tk`.

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter tk: shapeless.ops.hlist.Take[S,shapeless.Nat._1.N]
[error]     _ <- take(_1)
```

I know that I can help the compiler by simply exposing the state or by fixing `S`. But I don't want to! This extra-information seems redundant:

```scala
def take[S <: HList](hl: S, n: Nat)(implicit tk: Take[S, n.N]):
    IndexedState[S, tk.Out, Unit] = ???

for {
  hl <- init[Int :: String :: HNil]
  _  <- take(hl, _1)          // Redundant
  _  <- take[Int :: HNil](_1) // Redundant
  x  <- state("abc")
} yield x
```

Why in the first code snippet, scala compiler inferred `S` as `Nothing` instead of `Int :: String :: HNil`? I'm wondering if its possible to get this works without exposing the state or giving type information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think the compiler has enough information to infer `S` - all it knows about `S` is that there must be a `Take[S, n.N]` instance in scope, and those exist for a wide variety of different `S`. You and I know that the expected return type is `IndexedReaderWriterStateT[..., S, ...]`, but it's quite a convoluted path from there to realizing that `S` must be the type parameter to `take`. What happens when you expand out the expected type as e.g. `take(_1): IndexedReaderWriterStateT[...]`, does that get inferred correctly?

Comment: @Imm - Are you sure the compiler doesn't have enough information to infer `S`? The `init[Int :: String :: HNil]` gives an `IndexedState[Int :: String :: HNil, Int :: String :: HNil,Int :: String :: HNil]`. If we follow the types, then `flatMap`should take a function that constructs an `IndexedState[Int :: String :: HNil, ?, ?]`. We gives `{ _ => take(_1) }` which return a `IndexedState[S, tk.Out, Unit]`. I thought the matching between both should fix `S` to `Int :: String :: HNil`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles:

```
for {
  _ <- init[Int :: String :: HNil] flatMap { _  => take(_1) }
  x <- state("abc")
} yield x
```

The `for`-loop of your question is roughly translated to

```
init[Int :: String :: HNil] flatMap { _ =>
  take(_1) flatMap { _ =>
    state("abc") map { x =>
      x
    }
  }
}
```

and scalac seems not willing to infer the type argument of `take(_1)` given that it already has to infer some types below it and you call `flatMap` directly on it.

Comment: Do you know why scalac isn't willing to infer the type argument of `take(_1)`? I don't understand why the first code snippet (with the combination of sequence comprehensions and flatMap) compiles, whereas the second (the unsugared one) doesn't! Is it a scalac bug?